# What causes this failure to introduce a Bootstrap date picker in a Vue 3 app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, bootstrap-datepicker

I am working on a **Vue 3** and Bootstrap 5 app.

Needing a date picker that is compatible with Bootstrap, I choose **[bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker)**. I installed it via yarn.

In `main.js`:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import 'bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css'
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js'
import 'bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js'   
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import router from 'vue-router'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'
import axios from 'axios'
import App from './App.vue'

createApp(App)
              .use(router)
              .use(VueAxios, axios)
              .provide('$apiBaseUrl', 'http://apisource.com/api')
              .mount('#app')
```

In `components\Ui\DatepickerFrom.vue`:

```html
<template>
        <div class="input-group datepicker" id="date_from">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-append">
                <span class="input-group-text icon d-block">
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                </span>
            </span>
        </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'DatepickerFrom',

  mounted() {
    document.getElementById('date_from').datepicker();
  }
}
</script>
```

#### UPDATE

in `public/index.html` I added, imediatelly before `</body>`:

```html
<script src="<%= BASE_URL %>/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="<%= BASE_URL %>/node_modules/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script>
  (function(){
    $('#date_from').datepicker();
  })();
</script>
```

The problem persists.

#### The problem

Allthough, aparentlly, all the resources are available, the line `document.getElementById('date_from').datepicker()` throws this error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).datepicker is not a function
```

##### Where is my mistake?

Comment: Are you including jQuery, too? https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ indicates this is a requirement; the fact that it's only tested on Bootstrap v2 would give me pause, as well; that seems to indicate it's unmaintained. I'd recommend https://vcalendar.io/.

Comment: @ceejayoz I'd rather not use jQuery. What alternatives do I have?

Comment: @ceejayoz I added jQuery, but the problem remains.

Comment: Looking at your code snippets, I don't see any piece of code that makes initializes the div to register as a date picker

Comment: @KevinIzuchukwu It's `document.getElementById('date_from').datepicker()`.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir I see that. What I meant was I don't see anything in the code that would make that date picker function available on a regular dom element

Comment: @KevinIzuchukwu Using `this.$refs.dateFrom.datepicker()` doesn't work either.

Comment: it's a jquery extension, won't ever work in plain javascript, read the docs https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ that said, combining jquery with vue is bad practice in general

Comment: If you want it to work you have to use jQuery to initiate it `$('#date_from').datepicker()`

Comment: @RazvanZamfir u need to do it after the vue components rendered, so, inside mounted..

Comment: stop using jquery, use this one instead: https://icehaunter.github.io/vue3-datepicker

Comment: @Andy I have used that, but I can't overwrite its styles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Problems

`bootstrap-datepicker` does not augment `document` (or any other native API), so the following code would fail:

```js
// ❌ The `.datepicker` function does not exist
document.getElementById('date_from').datepicker();
```

In your second attempt, the `<script>` block that tries to load the datepicker most likely occurs **before** Vue has rendered the required template to the DOM, so the `#date_from` element could not be found.

#### Solution

`bootstrap-datepicker` is a jQuery extension, and it requires jQuery to be installed globally (on `window`) to run. Make sure to include the CDN link for `jquery` *and* `bootstrap-datepicker` before importing your Vue app in `index.html`, as seen in this example Vite `index.html`:

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite App</title>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"
      integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"
      integrity="sha512-T/tUfKSV1bihCnd+MxKD0Hm1uBBroVYBOYSk1knyvQ9VyZJpc/ALb4P0r6ubwVPSGB2GvjeoMAJJImBG12TiaQ=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    ></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.standalone.min.css"
      integrity="sha512-TQQ3J4WkE/rwojNFo6OJdyu6G8Xe9z8rMrlF9y7xpFbQfW5g8aSWcygCQ4vqRiJqFsDsE1T6MoAOMJkFXlrI9A=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The only way to use the library is through a jQuery call. Your component should use jQuery in the `mounted()` hook, and pass it a template ref to the container element instead of an element ID so that you could have multiple components on the same page if needed:

```html
// DatepickerFrom.vue
<template>
  <div class="input-group datepicker" ref="datepicker">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-append">
      <span class="input-group-text icon d-block">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
      </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    const $ = window.jQuery
    $(this.$refs.datepicker).datepicker()
  }
}
</script>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-datepicker-in-vue3?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyDatePicker.vue)

While it's possible to use this library in Vue, I recommend switching to a modern date-picker library that does not depend on jQuery. jQuery manipulates the DOM, which should be avoided as Vue manages its own virtual DOM, so a potential bug could appear when mixing the two.

Answer (score 0):

`input` tag taken as it is will only give you the properties available in native HTML. Adding the `datepicker` class to the input will only style your input but will not add any properties for the `input` HTML tag.

Instead of use `b-form-datepicker`. This is a datepicker tag provided by bootstrap for Vue.js.
Code as follows,

```
<b-form-datepicker v-model="dateValue"></b-form-datepicker>
```

Declare `dateValue` in your script part of the file.
For more info, refer: [Form Datepicker | Components | BootstrapVue](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-datepicker)

Comment: I don't see any sign in the question that OP is using BootstrapVue. That's not part of Bootstrap, it's a third-party add-on.

Comment: I am not using BootstrapVue, but Bootstrap 5. Successfully, until trying to implement a date picker.